# Horizontally centering a scrolling list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying have text cycle through a list of phrase, display on the same line and be centered no matter the string length and screen size. I have been able to get text to cycle through and display on the same line by finding a thread here on SE. The issue I am having now is trying to center that text within the parenting div. The strings are all going to be different lengths so I cannot set a width and the

s need to be absolutely positioned so they display on the same line.

I have been scratching my head on how to accomplish this and have exhausted Google and myself. Does anyone know how to accomplish this effect?

JSfiddle on what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/eh3sxko8/

html:

```
<div class="container">
 <ul id="cyclelist">
    <li>Some Title</li>   
    <li>Another Title</li>
    <li>Yet another</li>
 </ul>   
</div>
```

css:

```
.container{
width:100%;
}

ul#cyclelist {
position:relative;
overflow:hidden;
height:50px;
}
ul#cyclelist li {
opacity:0;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 var j = 0;
 var delay = 2000; //millisecond delay between cycles
 function cycleThru(){
         var jmax = $("ul#cyclelist li").length -1;
         $("ul#cyclelist li:eq(" + j + ")")
                 .animate({"opacity" : "1"} ,400)
                 .animate({"opacity" : "1"}, delay)
                 .animate({"opacity" : "0"}, 400, function(){
                         (j == jmax) ? j=0 : j++;
                         cycleThru();
                 });
         };

 cycleThru();

 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eh3sxko8/3/)**.

CSS:

```
ul#cyclelist {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

ul#cyclelist li {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! That helps so much. Not sure why that works but it does.